# Order of values when extracting Python dict to list

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am trying to get all values (except corresponding to a particular key) from a list of dicts by doing this:

```
fv = [[v for (k,v) in d.iteritems() if k is not 'xKey'] for d in someDict]
```

where `someDict` is like:

```
[{xKey:0.1,yKey:0.2,zKey:0.3},{yKey:0.9,xKey:0.7,zKey:0.4}...]
```

I know a dict doesn't have an inherent order. But my list of lists fv needs to have the values in order. I am thinking about sorting the dict on key and then doing what I just did. But is that guaranteed to work?

I know using `OrderedDict` is an option but it also seems to have inferior performance as compared to dict, which would be a concern for me since my dictionary is typically going to have huge amount of data.

Update : When I say I need values in order, they don't really have to be sorted.What I mean is I need to be able to retrieve the list of values in a fixed deterministic order each time.In the above example, I always want to get [[0.2,0.3],[0.9,0.4]] although it may not be a sorted order per se. Sorting would enforce one deterministic order.What I really care about is maintaining the position of values in the final list.e.g. Value of yKey must always be the first value in each list, the value of zKey must always be the second value in each list and so on even though ykey, zkey etc may be in any order in the dictionary.

Comment: I would use the `OrderedDict` and then measure the speed and see whether performance is a problem. It is often very difficult to predict performance without significant experience in the domain of interest.

Comment: I agree although the dictionary is going to grow in size with time and I understand we perhaps shouldn't-fix-it-if-it-isn't-broken but I don't want to revisit this in a week's time.

Comment: "a fixed deterministic order ... it may not be a sorted order per se"  You can't have an unspecified but deterministic order.  That's just asking for problems with the next release having a different unspecified by deterministic order.  Please make a finite, definite, and effective statement.  A hoped-for feature isn't going to work out well.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by getting this data out of the dicts? It seems like a strange requirement...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Good point.  If, for example, the point is two have two "parallel" dictionaries, it would be far smarter to have one dictionary with two values for each key.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am trying to construct a matrix of all values from the dictionary such that each row contains the values from each dictionary in the list and hence each column of the matrix has all values of a particular key across all dictionaries in the list.That is why I need the order of these values that I read to be consistent  so that each column indeed has values corresponding to the same key from all dictionaries in the list

Comment: S.Lott What I mean is there must be a specified order but it needn't be sorted by value.e.g. It will be fine if there is a way to read values of a dictionary in the order they were inserted in(except that it won't be deterministic in case of Python dicts unless I use OrderedDicts). Functionally what @android does below in his answer works for me I think.I am wondering if there are options or better ways to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the list of possible keys that your dicts may contain, the following solution might work for you:

```
allkeys = ...  # might be known; or obtained from available dicts by union;
               # 'xKey' can be removed at this stage to simplify the list
               # comprehension that follows
sortedKeys = sorted(allKeys)
list_of_values = [[d.get(k) for k in sortedKeys if k in d]
                                                   for d in list_of_dicts]
```

It might be slower than `iteritems` though. The `if k in d` part can be removed if all the dicts contain the same set of keys.

Answer (score 2):

The usual drill is this.

1. Build your dictionary as a dict.  Speed is excellent.
2. In the rare cases when you need the keys in order do one of the two:

   - Convert the entire thing to an OrderedDict
   - Sort the keys.  `for k in sorted( some_dict.keys() ):`

   The choice is one of amortization of the sort cost.  If you're doing one thing, sort.  if you're doing several things, build an OrderedDict.
3. In the really, really rare case where the values must be in some order, do this.

   ```
   ordered_values = list( sorted( some_dictionary.values() ) )
   ```

Comment: Is it just me, or is he asking for the sorted _values_?

Comment: "order.What I really care about is maintaining the position of values in the final list.".  So.  it's not clear if the keys **must** be sorted to guarantee a deterministic order or the values **must** be sorted to guarantee a deterministic order.  I vote for keys, since it's simpler.  The question is certainly unclear.

Comment: Your part 3 doesn't seem to work for me?  This is the case I need.